# Dropdown Cascating

Tags: c#, html, blazor

How do I when a dropdown category is chosen automatically to have the category's subcategories with Onchange, I'm not able to find a solution to this problem, i need help pls

```
<h1>Abrir Chamado</h1>

@if (_ListaCategorias.Count == 0)
{
    <p>Carregando...</p>
}
else
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select  class="form-control">
                <option value="1"> Selecione uma categoria </option>
                @foreach (var cat in _ListaCategorias)
                {
                    <option value="@cat.IdCategoria">@cat.Descricao</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="1"> Selecione uma Subcategoria</option>
            @foreach (var cat in _ListaSubCategorias)
            {
                <option value="@cat.IdSubCategoria">@cat.Descricao</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

@code {

```
private List<Categoria> _ListaCategorias = new List<Categoria>();
private List<SubCategoria> _ListaSubCategorias = new List<SubCategoria>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Categoria _Categoria = new Categoria();
    _ListaCategorias = await _Categoria.GetCategoriasAsync();

    SubCategoria _SubCategoria = new SubCategoria();
    _ListaSubCategorias = await _SubCategoria.GetSubCategoriasAsync();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The code below is a single Razor page demo to show you how you can achieve what I think you are trying to do.  I use a single object collection with filtering for categories and sub-categories.  you may need to do a query to get your sub-categories. I've also added a setter to `Country` to show you how to get the "event" when the country changes.  You'll need to adapt it to your code.

```cs
@page "/subcategory"
<h3>SubCategory</h3>

<span>Continent/Country</span>
<select @bind="Continent" placeholder="Choose a Continent">
    @foreach (var continent in Continents)
    {
        <option value="@continent">@continent</option>
    }
</select>

@if (Countries.Count > 0)
{
<select @bind="_country">
    <option value="">Select a Country</option>
    @foreach (var country in Countries)
    {
        <option value="@country">@country</option>
    }
</select>
}
<div class="m-3">Country Selected: @_country</div>

@code {

    class Model
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Continent { get; set; }
    }

    List<Model> models = new List<Model>()
{
        new Model {Country = "UK", Continent = "Europe"},
        new Model {Country = "Spain", Continent = "Europe"},
        new Model {Country = "Portugal", Continent = "Europe"},
        new Model {Country = "Thailand", Continent = "Asia"},
        new Model {Country = "Singapore", Continent = "Asia"},
        new Model {Country = "Brazil", Continent = "South America"},
        new Model {Country = "Chile", Continent = "South America"},
    };

    IEnumerable<string> Continents
        => models.Select(item => item.Continent).Distinct();

    List<string> Countries
        => models.Where(item => item.Continent.Equals(_continent)).Select(item => item.Country).ToList() ?? new List<string>();

    string Continent
    {
        get => _continent;
        set
        {
            if (!_continent.Equals(value))
            {
                _continent = value;
                _country = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    string Country
    {
        get => _country;
        set
        {
            if (!_country.Equals(value))
            {
                _country = value;
                // do whatever
            }
        }
    }


    string _continent = string.Empty;

    string _country = string.Empty;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Do what initializing you need to do here
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```